# PHP 7.1.29 - number in string behave wrong

Tags: php, string, csv, casting, numbers

I'm reading CSV file with two columns (ID, DATE). I want to get ID and use it for something, but what I'm getting is really weird. For first line I get "3" and after casting to integer I got 0. For sure, I have printed the value and the length of "3" is 4. WTF? Am I only tired or there is something wrong?
The second line works as expected.

**CSV FILE:**

```
3;2017-11-24 08:30:00+01
2;2017-10-20 09:00:00+02
```

**CODE:**

```php
if (($handle = fopen(__DIR__ . "/myfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        var_dump($data);
        var_dump($data[0]);
        var_dump(mb_strlen($data[0]));
        var_dump(gettype($data[0]));
        var_dump((int) $data[0]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "3"
  [1] =>
  string(22) "2017-11-24 08:30:00+01"
}
string(4) "3"
int(2)
string(6) "string"
int(0)
---------------------------
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "2"
  [1] =>
  string(22) "2017-10-20 09:00:00+02"
}
string(1) "2"
int(1)
string(6) "string"
int(2)
```

### **EDIT:**

When I change the order of lines, it always do only first line. BOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was encoding. After changing from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 it works fine. What is still weird is that PHP define array key as "3" with length 4 and after casting to int it return 0.